# Set default plot attributes for a dataframe

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, default, lattice

Many packages contain dataframes where plot(df) produces specific output. eg. nlme contains the 'Dialyzer' data-frame which on plot(Dialyzer) produces a plot using trellis (lattice package) where the code would actually be:

```
dotplot(rate ~ pressure | Subject, data="Dialyzer")
```

The code for this seems to be contained in the dataframes attributes: can anyone point me to a guide or include a guide on how to set the default plot for a dataframe up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is determined by the class of the object. Notice the class of Dialyzer "data.frame".

```
> class(Dialyzer)
[1] "nfnGroupedData" "nfGroupedData"  "groupedData"    "data.frame"
```

When you call plot, it goes through the entries of this class and tries to find `plot.*` method. First one it finds is used. If everything fails, there's always `data.frame`.

```
> methods("plot")
 [1] plot.acf*              plot.ACF*              plot.augPred*          plot.compareFits*      plot.data.frame*      
 [6] plot.decomposed.ts*    plot.default           plot.dendrogram*       plot.density*          plot.ecdf             
[11] plot.factor*           plot.formula*          plot.function          plot.gls*              plot.hclust*          
[16] plot.histogram*        plot.HoltWinters*      plot.intervals.lmList* plot.isoreg*           plot.lm*              
[21] plot.lme               plot.lmList*           plot.medpolish*        plot.mlm*              plot.nffGroupedData*  
[26] plot.nfnGroupedData*   plot.nls*              plot.nmGroupedData*    plot.pdMat*            plot.ppr*             
[31] plot.prcomp*           plot.princomp*         plot.profile.nls*      plot.ranef.lme*        plot.ranef.lmList*    
[36] plot.raster*           plot.shingle*          plot.simulate.lme*     plot.spec*             plot.stepfun          
[41] plot.stl*              plot.table*            plot.trellis*          plot.ts                plot.tskernel*        
[46] plot.TukeyHSD*         plot.Variogram*
```

If you want to use a specific method, you can call it explicitly using `plot.*`, e.g. `plot.default`.

Comment: Thanks Roman, having searched around your answer I found this:https://github.com/cran/nlme/blob/master/R/groupedData.R where it specifies how the data-frames are grouped in nlme.

Answer (score 1):

R is *polymorphic*. It means that same function can lead to different operations for different classes of objects. You could apply `plot()` to many different types of objects, you will get a different kind of plot for each one. We could say the same, for example, for `print()`, `summary()` and many others.

Polymorphism makes things easier to remember. If a function is new to you, just try running `plot()` on the function’s output; it will likely work. If you are programmer, polymorphism allows writing fairly general code, without worrying about what type of object is being manipulated, because the underlying class mechanisms take care of that.
Functions that work with polymorphism, such as `plot()` and `print()`,
are known as *generic*. When a generic function is called, R transmits the call to the relative class method: it will reroute the call to a function defined for the specific object’s class.